# if I do sched_setaffinity in a process, do the threads spawned by it get affected

Tags: pthreads, affinity

If I do this : CreateThreads, setsched_affinity to CPU 0, then will all the threads also have affinity to CPU 0
If instead I reverse the sequence of action i.e. set_schedaffinity first and then create threads , will the threads have affinity

I am creating threads using pthreads library. Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 6):

The `sched_setaffinity()` call is Linux-specific, so this answer applies there.

A call to `sched_setaffinity()` affects only a single thread.  A thread created with `pthread_create()` inherits the CPU affinity mask of its parent.

This means that if you change the affinity of the current thread after creating other threads, their affinity will remain the default; but if you do it in the reverse order, they will inherit the altered affinity set.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, does `sched_setaffinity` received `pid_t pid`, from `pthread_self()` or `getpid()`?

Comment: @lior.i: `pthread_self()` returns a `pthread_t` type, not a PID/TID. `gettid()` returns the thread ID of the current thread.